# Oracle: Select time in HH:MI format eg: 30:00

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time

How can i Select my Runtime column (defaults to seconds) to display time in HH:Mi format such as 106680 seconds = 29:38. By default HH24:Mi wraps the time beyond 24 hours.

Comment: You'll find answer here: [Seconds to hours:minutes:seconds format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003918/oracle-convert-seconds-to-hoursminutesseconds)

Comment: Are you sure it's not just an improper NLS setting? (Sql developer tools-preferences-database-NLS (DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS) is default I think.

Comment: No, it was not a format problem. I was able to change my format however i wanted to, but Oracle just does not have a HH:Mi format that goes beyond 24 hours.

Comment: Thank you @PrzemyslawKruglej  Your link helped. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
Select to_char(TRUNC(runtimeCol/3600),'09') || ':' || to_char(TRUNC(MOD(runtimeCol,3600)/60),'09')  from yourTable
```

Comment: @kkoolpatz did this work for you? If so please indicate accordingly!

Comment: This worked very well, except there is a space after the colon. But that was okay.Thank you very much.  
 `TO_CHAR 
 -------
  29: 38
  30: 00
  25: 47
  33: 00
  32: 39`

Comment: I was able to get around the space issue by using FM00 instead of 09
`to_char(TRUNC(MOD((ENDTIME-STARTIME),3600)/60),'FM00')`