# How to convert miliseconds to hh mm ss format in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a Database table having a column 'time' which has milliseconds stored. I need to convert that in hours:minutes:seconds format. 
Can anyone please help how to do that? I think it requires a function. I tried one , but it only works for hours less than 24 hours. I need it to convert greater than 24 hours as well.
Note: the datatype of the Time column is Varchar2.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If it is mySql, 
**SELECT SEC_TIME(seconds/1000);** 
does what you want exactly, but if it is oracle sql, here is a link: [Oracle Convert Seconds to Hours:Minutes:Seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003918/oracle-convert-seconds-to-hoursminutesseconds)
Adding 1000 in the denominator of solution in the link does task of converting milliseconds to hh:mm:ss upto 9999 hours. Hope it helps! Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! i found below code on the link you mentioned:

Comment: SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(x/3600),'FM9900') || ':' ||
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(x,3600)/60),'FM00') || ':' ||
    TO_CHAR(MOD(x,60),'FM00')
FROM DUAL

Comment: But it is just conversion of seconds to hh:mm:ss . I need milliseconds to hh:mm:ss. can you please let me know how to add 1000 in denominator of solution? i didn't get that.

Answer (score 0):

milliseconds to hh:mm:ss

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(s/3600000),'FM9900') || ':' || TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(s,3600000)/60000),'FM00') 
|| ':' ||TO_CHAR(MOD(s,60000),'FM00')
FROM DUAL ;
```