# Average of Feed / Event Arrival Time for SLO

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a table where Feed name and it's arrival times are captured. Was trying to get average feed arrival time, tried two ways to do that:

1. captured only time, converted it to minutes, used avg function and then converted back to time
2. captured only time, used median function

But in both the cases issue comes when the feed arrival time is near to mid night where sometimes feed comes before mid night e.g. 23:40 and sometimes after midnight e.g. 12:22. In this case the average comes as middle of the day due to values.

Can someone help how a query can be built in ORACLE to capture average time in such scenario?

```
8/31/2022 12:02:09.434916 AM

8/30/2022 12:51:01.950574 AM

8/26/2022 11:55:16.899643 PM

8/26/2022 12:32:16.250415 AM

8/25/2022 12:11:48.869983 AM

8/23/2022 11:40:21.081020 PM

8/23/2022 12:16:59.638991 AM

8/19/2022 11:19:15.580283 PM

8/18/2022 11:23:03.077817 PM

8/17/2022 11:19:07.286905 PM

8/16/2022 11:26:33.472424 PM

8/15/2022 11:17:14.263464 PM

8/12/2022 11:50:07.724526 PM

8/11/2022 11:47:15.508658 PM

8/10/2022 11:50:15.372413 PM

8/10/2022 1:09:52.835009 AM

8/9/2022 12:24:36.999384 AM

8/6/2022 12:22:48.737356 AM

8/5/2022 12:21:50.502211 AM

8/4/2022 12:18:59.592631 AM

8/3/2022 12:14:46.761802 AM

8/2/2022 12:16:51.087926 AM
```

Additionally - is there a way to capture running average to identify when we see increase in average? i.e. with time the feed arrival starts to get delayed but due to ongoing nature unless we analyze data it is difficult to capture that.

Just to add trying to built SLI / SLO in case of an ETL process where feed comes, gets loaded and the SLIs here can be taken as data availability time for users based on region. (accuracy of data would be taken up later).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not worried about the fractional seconds then you can convert the values to a `DATE` and find the difference from the nearest midnight (as a `NUMBER`) and then average those to get the average time.

```sql
SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL(
         AVG(
           CASE
           WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM value) < 12
           THEN CAST(value AS DATE) - TRUNC(value)
           ELSE CAST(value AS DATE) - TRUNC(value) - 1
           END
         ),
         'DAY'
       ) AS avg_delivery_time
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS 
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/31/2022 12:02:09.434916 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/30/2022 12:51:01.950574 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/26/2022 11:55:16.899643 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/26/2022 12:32:16.250415 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/25/2022 12:11:48.869983 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/23/2022 11:40:21.081020 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/23/2022 12:16:59.638991 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/19/2022 11:19:15.580283 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/18/2022 11:23:03.077817 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/17/2022 11:19:07.286905 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/16/2022 11:26:33.472424 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/15/2022 11:17:14.263464 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/12/2022 11:50:07.724526 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/11/2022 11:47:15.508658 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/10/2022 11:50:15.372413 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/10/2022 1:09:52.835009 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/9/2022 12:24:36.999384 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/6/2022 12:22:48.737356 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/5/2022 12:21:50.502211 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/4/2022 12:18:59.592631 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/3/2022 12:14:46.761802 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8/2/2022 12:16:51.087926 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | AVG_DELIVERY_TIME |
> | --- |
> | +000000000 00:02:22.772727273 |

(2 minutes 22 seconds past midnight)

*[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/usSbqDuI)*

Answer (score 0):

Following your attempt with taking out time, converting it to minutes (seconds in this answer) and calculating avg values (both - total avg of all rows and running avg of previous rows with current row). There is a backwards conversions of avg seconds back to time values.
With your sample data :

| VALUE |
| --- |
| 31-AUG-22 00.02.09.434916000 |
| 30-AUG-22 00.51.01.950574000 |
| 26-AUG-22 23.55.16.899643000 |
| 26-AUG-22 00.32.16.250415000 |
| 25-AUG-22 00.11.48.869983000 |
| 23-AUG-22 23.40.21.081020000 |
| 23-AUG-22 00.16.59.638991000 |
| 19-AUG-22 23.19.15.580283000 |
| 18-AUG-22 23.23.03.077817000 |
| 17-AUG-22 23.19.07.286905000 |
| 16-AUG-22 23.26.33.472424000 |
| 15-AUG-22 23.17.14.263464000 |
| 12-AUG-22 23.50.07.724526000 |
| 11-AUG-22 23.47.15.508658000 |
| 10-AUG-22 23.50.15.372413000 |
| 10-AUG-22 01.09.52.835009000 |
| 09-AUG-22 00.24.36.999384000 |
| 06-AUG-22 00.22.48.737356000 |
| 05-AUG-22 00.21.50.502211000 |
| 04-AUG-22 00.18.59.592631000 |
| 03-AUG-22 00.14.46.761802000 |
| 02-AUG-22 00.16.51.087926000 |

Firstly, times are formated like hh24 (instead of AM/PM) and converted to seconds to do the AVG with later.

```sql
WITH
    tbl_2 AS 
        (
            Select 
                To_Date(To_Char(VALUE, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "DATE_TIME",
                      (To_Number(To_Char(To_Date(To_Char(VALUE, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'hh24')) * 3600) +  
                      (To_Number(To_Char(To_Date(To_Char(VALUE, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'mi')) * 60) + 
                       To_Number(To_Char(To_Date(To_Char(VALUE, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'ss')) "SECONDS"
            From tbl
        )
```

This is used as the source data for the main SQL

```sql
SELECT
    DATE_TIME "DATE_TIME",
    JUST_TIME "JUST_TIME",
    SECONDS "SECONDS",
    RUNNING_AVG_SECONDS "RUNNING_AVG_SECONDS",
    
    To_Char(Trunc(RUNNING_AVG_SECONDS / 3600), 'FM9900') || ':' ||
    To_Char(Trunc(Mod(RUNNING_AVG_SECONDS, 3600) / 60), 'FM00') || ':' ||
    To_Char(Mod(RUNNING_AVG_SECONDS, 60), 'FM00') "RUNNING_AVG_TIME", 

    TOTAL_AVG_SECONDS "TOTAL_AVG_SECONDS",
    To_Char(Trunc(TOTAL_AVG_SECONDS / 3600), 'FM9900') || ':' ||
    To_Char(Trunc(Mod(TOTAL_AVG_SECONDS, 3600) / 60), 'FM00') || ':' ||
    To_Char(Mod(TOTAL_AVG_SECONDS, 60), 'FM00') "TOTAL_AVG_TIME"
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            To_Char(DATE_TIME, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "DATE_TIME",
            To_Char(DATE_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss') "JUST_TIME",
            SECONDS "SECONDS", 
            Round(AVG(SECONDS) OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY DATE_TIME ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), 6) "RUNNING_AVG_SECONDS",
            Round(AVG(SECONDS) OVER(), 6) "TOTAL_AVG_SECONDS"
        FROM 
            tbl_2 
        ORDER BY 
            DATE_TIME
    )
```

I selected some additional columns so you could control the results. Used AVG analytic function to get both TOTAL_AVG_SECONDS and RUNNING_AVG_SECONDS. Both of the columns are converted back to time (using accepted answer from [Oracle Convert Seconds to Hours:Minutes:Seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003918/oracle-convert-seconds-to-hoursminutesseconds) : thank's Mike). Here is the resulting dataset:

| DATE_TIME | JUST_TIME | SECONDS | RUNNING_AVG_SECONDS | RUNNING_AVG_TIME | TOTAL_AVG_SECONDS | TOTAL_AVG_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08/02/2022 00:16:51 | 00:16:51 | 1011 | 1011 | 00:16:51 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/03/2022 00:14:46 | 00:14:46 | 886 | 948.5 | 00:15:49 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/04/2022 00:18:59 | 00:18:59 | 1139 | 1012 | 00:16:52 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/05/2022 00:21:50 | 00:21:50 | 1310 | 1086.5 | 00:18:07 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/06/2022 00:22:48 | 00:22:48 | 1368 | 1142.8 | 00:19:03 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/09/2022 00:24:36 | 00:24:36 | 1476 | 1198.33333 | 00:19:58 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/10/2022 01:09:52 | 01:09:52 | 4192 | 1626 | 00:27:06 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/10/2022 23:50:15 | 23:50:15 | 85815 | 12149.625 | 03:22:30 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/11/2022 23:47:15 | 23:47:15 | 85635 | 20314.6667 | 05:38:35 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/12/2022 23:50:07 | 23:50:07 | 85807 | 26863.9 | 07:27:44 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/15/2022 23:17:14 | 23:17:14 | 83834 | 32043 | 08:54:03 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/16/2022 23:26:33 | 23:26:33 | 84393 | 36405.5 | 10:06:46 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/17/2022 23:19:07 | 23:19:07 | 83947 | 40062.5385 | 11:07:43 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/18/2022 23:23:03 | 23:23:03 | 84183 | 43214 | 12:00:14 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/19/2022 23:19:15 | 23:19:15 | 83955 | 45930.0667 | 12:45:30 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/23/2022 00:16:59 | 00:16:59 | 1019 | 43123.125 | 11:58:43 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/23/2022 23:40:21 | 23:40:21 | 85221 | 45599.4706 | 12:39:59 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/25/2022 00:11:48 | 00:11:48 | 708 | 43105.5 | 11:58:26 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/26/2022 00:32:16 | 00:32:16 | 1936 | 40938.6842 | 11:22:19 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/26/2022 23:55:16 | 23:55:16 | 86116 | 43197.55 | 11:59:58 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/30/2022 00:51:01 | 00:51:01 | 3061 | 41286.2857 | 11:28:06 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |
| 08/31/2022 00:02:09 | 00:02:09 | 129 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 | 39415.5 | 10:56:56 |

Regards...