# Is it possible to do sum of time interval

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some data of time interval. Now I want to do sum from those time interval data. So how can I do that? Data are like as..

| START_TIME | END_TIME | PROCESS_RUN_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9/8/2022 8:45:20.631429 PM | 9/8/2022 8:45:23.257592 PM | +000000000 00:00:02.626163000 |
| 9/8/2022 8:45:24.211717 PM | 9/8/2022 8:45:24.896982 PM | +000000000 00:00:00.685265000 |
| 9/8/2022 8:45:25.414725 PM | 9/8/2022 8:45:27.375699 PM | +000000000 00:00:01.960974000 |
| 9/8/2022 8:45:34.608107 PM | 9/8/2022 8:45:35.027469 PM | +000000000 00:00:00.419362000 |
| 9/8/2022 8:45:35.341021 PM | 9/8/2022 8:45:42.104194 PM | +000000000 00:00:06.763173000 |
| 9/8/2022 8:50:43.314294 PM | 9/8/2022 8:53:05.335864 PM | +000000000 00:02:22.021570000 |

Here **START_TIME** and **END_TIME** are `TIMESTAMP` datatype and **PROCESS_RUN_TIME** is `VARCHAR2` datatype.

I do following. But **ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source** message pop-up.

```
`SELECT   NUMTODSINTERVAL (SUM (EXTRACT (DAY FROM PROCESS_RUN_TIME)), 'DAY')
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL (SUM (EXTRACT (HOUR FROM PROCESS_RUN_TIME)), 'HOUR')
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL (SUM (EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM PROCESS_RUN_TIME)),
                          'MINUTE')
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL (SUM (EXTRACT (SECOND FROM PROCESS_RUN_TIME)),
                          'SECOND')
          AS SUM_OF_TIME
  FROM CONV_PROCESS_RUN_TIME;`
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the datatype of the PROCESS_RUN_TIME column?

Comment: @Vlookup it's **TIMETAMP** datatype column.

Answer (score 1):

Do not store the difference between two times as a `VARCHAR2` data type, use an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type (and in this case, it can be a virtual column):

```sql
CREATE TABLE conv_process_run_time (
  START_TIME       TIMESTAMP(6),
  END_TIME         TIMESTAMP(6),
  PROCESS_RUN_TIME INTERVAL DAY(3) TO SECOND(6)
                   GENERATED ALWAYS AS (END_TIME - START_TIME)
);
```

Then you can insert the sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO conv_process_run_time (START_TIME, END_TIME)
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-08-09 20:45:20.631429', TIMESTAMP '2022-08-09 20:45:23.257592' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-08-09 20:45:24.211717', TIMESTAMP '2022-08-09 20:45:24.896982' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-08-09 20:45:25.414725', TIMESTAMP '2022-08-09 20:45:27.375699' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-08-09 20:45:34.608107', TIMESTAMP '2022-08-09 20:45:35.027469' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-08-09 20:45:35.341021', TIMESTAMP '2022-08-09 20:45:42.104194' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-08-09 20:50:43.314294', TIMESTAMP '2022-08-09 20:53:05.335864' FROM DUAL;
```

And your query works:

```sql
SELECT   NUMTODSINTERVAL (SUM (EXTRACT (DAY FROM PROCESS_RUN_TIME)), 'DAY')
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL (SUM (EXTRACT (HOUR FROM PROCESS_RUN_TIME)), 'HOUR')
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL (SUM (EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM PROCESS_RUN_TIME)),
                          'MINUTE')
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL (SUM (EXTRACT (SECOND FROM PROCESS_RUN_TIME)),
                          'SECOND')
          AS SUM_OF_TIME
  FROM CONV_PROCESS_RUN_TIME;
```

And outputs:

| SUM_OF_TIME |
| --- |
| +000000000 00:02:34.476507000 |

---

If you want to use your table then ignore the `PROCESS_RUN_TIME` column (as it is not useful as a string data-type) and use the difference between `START_TIME` and `END_TIME`:

```sql
SELECT   NUMTODSINTERVAL (SUM (EXTRACT (DAY FROM END_TIME - START_TIME)), 'DAY')
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL (SUM (EXTRACT (HOUR FROM END_TIME - START_TIME)), 'HOUR')
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL (SUM (EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM END_TIME - START_TIME)),
                          'MINUTE')
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL (SUM (EXTRACT (SECOND FROM END_TIME - START_TIME)),
                          'SECOND')
          AS SUM_OF_TIME
  FROM CONV_PROCESS_RUN_TIME;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Is1GNDs4)

Answer (score 0):

Sample data (table name is a_tbl):

| START_TIME | END_TIME | RUN_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13-SEP-22 06.47.42.252228000 | 13-SEP-22 06.48.47.077579000 | +000000000 00:01:02.408990 |
| 13-SEP-22 06.47.59.420078000 | 13-SEP-22 06.48.47.077579000 | +000000000 00:00:45.241140 |
| 13-SEP-22 06.48.36.964897000 | 13-SEP-22 06.48.47.077579000 | +000000000 00:00:07.696321 |
| 13-SEP-22 06.48.39.616207000 | 13-SEP-22 06.48.47.077579000 | +000000000 00:00:05.045011 |
| 13-SEP-22 06.48.42.416134000 | 13-SEP-22 06.48.47.077579000 | +000000000 00:00:02.245084 |
| 13-SEP-22 06.48.44.650970000 | 13-SEP-22 06.48.47.077579000 | +000000000 00:00:00.010248 |

```sql
WITH
    runtimes AS
        (
            SELECT 
            RUN_TIME,
            To_Char(To_TimeStamp(SubStr(RUN_TIME, InStr(RUN_TIME, ' ') + 1), 'hh24:mi:ss:ff'), 'hh24') "RUN_HH",
            To_Char(To_TimeStamp(SubStr(RUN_TIME, InStr(RUN_TIME, ' ') + 1), 'hh24:mi:ss:ff'), 'mi') "RUN_MI",
            To_Char(To_TimeStamp(SubStr(RUN_TIME, InStr(RUN_TIME, ' ') + 1), 'hh24:mi:ss:ff'), 'ss') "RUN_SS",
            To_Char(To_TimeStamp(SubStr(RUN_TIME, InStr(RUN_TIME, ' ') + 1), 'hh24:mi:ss:ff'), 'ff') "RUN_FF"
            From a_tbl
        )
Select
    Sum((To_Number(RUN_HH) * 3600) + (To_Number(RUN_MI) * 60) + To_Number(RUN_SS) + To_Number('0.' || RUN_FF)) "SECONDS"
From
    runtimes
```

Result in seconds is:

| SECONDS |
| --- |
| 122.646794 |

Regards...

**Addition**:
To convert seconds to HH24:mi:ss.ff you can use modifyed Mike's answer from ( [Oracle Convert Seconds to Hours:Minutes:Seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003918/oracle-convert-seconds-to-hoursminutesseconds) ), I added just the fractions here:

```sql
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SECONDS/3600),'FM9900') || ':' ||
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(SECONDS,3600)/60),'FM00') || ':' ||
    TO_CHAR(MOD(SECONDS,60)-1,'FM00') || '.' || 
    SubStr(SECONDS, InStr(To_Char(SECONDS), '.')+1) "TOTAL_RUN_TIME"
FROM
    (
        Select
            Sum((To_Number(RUN_HH) * 3600) + (To_Number(RUN_MI) * 60) + To_Number(RUN_SS) + To_Number('0.' || RUN_FF)) "SECONDS"
        From
            runtimes
    )
--  R e s u l t :
--  
--  TOTAL_RUN_TIME    
--  ------------------
--  00:02:02.646794
```

Comment: From your query I get all the time in seconds. Is there any possibility to get the difference in days, hours, minutes, seconds & milliseconds at a time?

Comment: @ASadman Zlhan: I have just posted the Addition with conversion from seconds to hours/minutes/seconds/fractions. I'm sure yyou cand do the days/months... etc yourself. Regards...